# upgrading from .Net 3.5 to 4.5 causing telerik error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

We have updated a ASP.NET WebForms website from .Net framework 3.5 to 4.5 . we are using telerik controls, website is compiled and working fine but i can see following error in log file. looks telerik related issue

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): This is an invalid webresource request.
  at 
System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader
.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.
System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.
System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()"
```

any idea how to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Some Telerik control is requesting a resource that is not there.  Did you update the Telerik version as well?  There are different ones for the .Net version you are using.  There is a bunch of information in this blog post, but if the website is working and you are just seeing these errors in the log file, you might consider ignoring them.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/this-is-an-invalid-webresource-request-exception